# In Wordpress while trying to access theme editor it gives "internal server error"

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, plesk

I am Trying to access theme editor, when i click on theme editor it shows "internal server error", even when i try to install some of the plugins it shows same error.

Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator to inform of the time the error occurred and of anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: Please post the complete error message from the error log. There are so many things that could have caused the error and we don't have enough information

Comment: You may need to make some edits to your `wp-config.php` file to enable error logging. See: [Debugging in WordPress documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)

Comment: You might have updated your theme and the editor along with it. In such case, you need to update your WordPress. Or the other way around